# NodeJS: WriteStream close event runs after Promise is rejected

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using the following code to download images from a website. Sometimes if there is an error the website will return a HTML page instead of an image. To avoid downloading a HTML page instead of an image, when I receive the response header and if the content-type is HTML I reject my download function. When I reject my function in the response event my rejection is successfully handled outside of my download function. However, the download function will also still continue to run even after it has been rejected (as if return is being ignored) and will end up eventually running the code inside the writeStream's end event.

How do I stop my download function from continuing to run after it has been rejected?

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const request = require('request');
var probe = require('probe-image-size');
var progress = require('request-progress');

var filename = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/myimage.jpg';
var writeSteam = fs.createWriteStream(filename)
var req = request(createRequestHeaders('www.linktomyimage.com/image.jpg'));

downloadImage(req, filename).then((fileInfo) => {
    console.log('Successfully downloaded.');
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log('Handle rejections and do something else.');
});

function createRequestHeaders(url) {
    var cookie = `userid=${userid}; phash=${phash};`;
    return {
        'url': url,
        'method': 'GET',
        'gzip': true,
        'headers': {
            'Referer': `https://${website}/`,
            'Cookie': cookie
        }
    };
}

function downloadImage(req, filename) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var response = null;
        var bytes;
        var dirname = path.dirname(filename);
        if (!fs.existsSync(dirname)) fs.ensureDirSync(dirname);

        progress(req, { delay: 0 }).on('progress', function (state) {
            updateDownloadSpeed(state.speed);
        }).on('end', function () {
            writeSteam.on('close', () => {
                if (bytes !== writeSteam.bytesWritten) {
                    // Here the write stream is closed, so we can compare the property bytesWritten with the bytes we expected to receive
                    console.log('The size is not equal! Image is corrupt!')
                    reject({ 'name': 'ImageCorrupt' });
                    return;
                } else if (response.statusCode === 200) {
                    var input = require('fs').createReadStream(filename);
                    probe(input).then(result => {
                        input.destroy();
                        if (result != null) {
                            resolve({
                                bytes: bytes, width: result.width,
                                height: result.height,
                            });
                        } else {
                            reject({ 'name': 'ImageMissingOrCorrupt' });
                            return;
                        }
                    }).catch((error) => {
                        reject(error);
                        return;
                    });
                } else {
                    // This is never triggered when the download stops and the image is truncated
                    reject({ 'name': 'StatusCodeError', 'message': response.statusCode });
                    return;
                }
            });
        }).on('response', function (resp) {
            response = resp;
            if (mime.getExtension(response.headers['content-type']) == 'html') {
                // Even if this is triggered and the Promise rejects, the code under the writeStream's close event still triggers
                reject({ 'name': 'RecievedHTML' });
                return;
            } else {
                // Get the expected size of the file so we can test if it is entirely downloaded later
                bytes = parseInt(response.headers['content-length']);
            }
        }).on('error', function (error) {
            reject(error);
            return;
        }).pipe(writeSteam);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you call `pipe` without any condition.

Remove the `pipe(writeStream)` from the bottom, and place it within the `else` block:

```js
            if (mime.getExtension(response.headers['content-type']) == 'html') {
                // Even if this is triggered and the Promise rejects, the code under the writeStream's close event still triggers
                reject({ 'name': 'RecievedHTML' });
                return;
            } else {
                // Get the expected size of the file so we can test if it is entirely downloaded later
                bytes = parseInt(response.headers['content-length']);
                this.pipe(writeStream);
            }
```

Comment: What if instead something goes wrong and triggers the error event of the request? Would the writeStream end event still trigger?

Comment: I think in case an error occurs during request, then `response` event is not emitted at all, so `writeStream` doesn't even starts.